# Fetch a Single Key Value pair from my Retrofit response

Tags: android, retrofit

I am getting a response from the GET method in the form of

> {data : { "type " : User ........ "attribute" : { "isemailverified" : false.....}....}

I want to fetch the value of `isemailverified`

I am using Retrofit to fetch data

```
useCaseFactory.getUserDomainModel().GetUser(userId, withDataArray, null, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();                
                        System.out.println(response.body().string());

                    }
```

Comment: you need to parse the JSON from response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)